# Only variables should be passed by reference Strict standards on line 138

Tags: php, arrays, variables, strict

```
usort($qus_with_ans, "qus_sort");
$ary_val = max(array_column($qus_with_ans, 'updated_at'));
$ary_key = array_search($ary_val, array_column($qus_with_ans, 'updated_at'));
$k = $qus_with_ans[$ary_key];
$curnt_sub_id = $k['subject_id'];
$curnt_sub_name = $k['s_name'];
$last_question_key = end(array_keys($qus_with_ans));
```

We have a error  Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on last line of code i can't understand why error comes Please fix my issue
line no. 138 are  `$last_question_key = end(array_keys($qus_with_ans));`

Comment: Set `array_keys($qus_with_ans)` to a variable, then pass that variable into `end`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function return in `end` function and should convert it to the variable.

```
$keys=array_keys($qus_with_ans);
$last_question_key = end($keys);
```

However, use `arrya_pop` which is pushing-out last element from the array

```
$last_question_key = array_pop(array_keys($qus_with_ans));
```

If you anyway don't have intension to use keys elsewhere from performance point of view.